# Point-Biserial Correlation in Java

Tags: java, statistics, correlation

I have a binary variable (which is either TRUE or FALSE) and I have a continuous variable in the interval [0,1].

I am interested in the correlation of the two. 
Therefore, I would like to use the Point-biserial correlation coefficient.

Is there a standard library in Java that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

As Point-biserial correlation is a special case of Pearson’s correlation coefficient you can use [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/correlation/PearsonsCorrelation.html) from Apache Math

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I am not a statistics expert. Can I do it in the following way?

`double[] binary = {1.0, 0.0, 1.0};
double[] continuous = {5.0, 4.0, 6.0};
PearsonsCorrelation p = new PearsonsCorrelation();
double result = p.correlation(binary, continuous);`

Comment: but your interval from 0 to 1?